# Pushing vectors back at different positions

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm having a slight problem understanding this.

Basically I have a 2D vector containing blocks that are of size 1024x1024 and I compute the total energy of these blocks. If the block therefore is within a certain threshold value, then they can be stored inside another 2D vector. The problem is that, I need to capture (push back) multiple blocks until the threshold then becomes negative.. Here is an example:

```
blocks[0] = 0.124 <- This is not pushed back
blocks[1] = 0.123 <- This is not pushed back
blocks[2] = 0.456 <- This is not pushed back 
blocks[3] = 1.23 <- This is pushed back to vector[0]
blocks[4] = 2.45 <- This is pushed back to vector[0]
blocks[5] = 7.23 <- This is pushed back to vector[0]
blocks[6] = 8.12 <- This is pushed back to vector[0]
blocks[7] = 0.12 <- This is not pushed back
blocks[8] = 0.124 <- This is not pushed back
blocks[9] = 0.125 <- This is not pushed back
blocks[10] = 8.123 <- This is pushed back to vector[1]
blocks[11] = 8.123 <- This is pushed back to vector[1]
blocks[12] = 8.123 <- This is pushed back to vector[1]
blocks[13] = 0.12 <- This is not pushed back
```

So basically, when the threshold is true for a block, the block is then inserted into a 2D vector at position[i] until the block becomes negative. When the value becomes true again, the blocks are pushed back to position[i + 1]

My thoughts so far:

If I have two variables that store how many blocks need to be pushed back, and another variable that stores at what position the vector is being pushed back in.. I.e. `currentpos[1]` so therefore the next position would be `currentpos[2]`

Any help you can offer, pseudocode would be even better.

EDIT:

Here is the threshold function:

```
bool threshold (vector<double> val)
{

//short threshold = 10000;
float sum = 0.0;
for(unsigned i=0; (i < val.size()); i++)
{
    sum += (val[i]*val[i]);
}
return (sum > 0.082);
```

}

And then I have the following:

```
std::vector<vector<double> > blocks = splitVector(1024, 1024); // this is fine, it works!
// then
std::vector<vector<double> > clusters;
for(unsigned i=0; (i < blocks.size()); i++)
{
   if(threshold(blocks[i])) { 
   // true
   clusters[i].push_back(d[i]);
   }else{
    // false do not do anything
   }
}
```

But the problem that I'm having is that, "clusters" will only ever contain the amount of "positive" blocks that have been returned. So `blocks.size() = 745 (size)` where `clusters.size() = 6` does this make more sense?

EDIT -- This example works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool energy(const std::vector<double> &vals)
{
float sum = 0.0;
for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
{
    sum += (vals[i]*vals[i]);
}
//cout << sum << endl;
return (sum >= 5);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

std::vector<vector<double> > vals {

    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // This has an energy of "0" -> does not count
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, //This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // This has an energy of "0" -> does not count && start a new vector
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
};
std::vector<vector<double> > clusters; 

//std::for_each(vals.begin(), vals.end(), energy);

int j = 0;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
{
    if(energy(vals[i]))
    {
        clusters.resize(j + 1);

        clusters[j] = vals[i];
    }else if(!energy(vals[i]) && energy(vals[i+1]))
    {
        j++;
    }
}

 }
```

However, instead of "concatenating" the values, it just overrides them, so `clusters[0]` will just contain the values: `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` instead of `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1} + {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} + {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` by the `+` operator, I mean concatenation and not the SUM of the elements.

How would it therefore be possible to concatenate the values?

Comment: Could you define "block becomes negative" more precisely? Does that mean going below the threshold (which is equal to `1` in your example?) or does it mean that the one-step finite difference is negative?

Comment: What is `blocks`, your anonymous 2D vector? How is it 2D? Do you mean _if the block's energy is within a threshold_? How does a threshold become negative? Why do you show a 1D vector of scalar values, all of which are positive?

Comment: _the block is then inserted into a 2D vector at position[i] until the block becomes negative_ ... how does inserting a block make it negative?  I think you need to write a self-contained toy example if you can't explain any more clearly than this.

Comment: @Useless Ok, let me make a toy example =)

Comment: @Useless I've updated my post to include a test dummy.. Does this make more sense?

Comment: So now your question is how to concatenate vectors ... you want your 4 consecutive `{1,1,1,1,1}` flattened into a vector length 20 filled with 1s, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following psuedocode:

```
bool flag = false;
int j = 0;
for i in blocks
{
 if(blocks[i] > 0)
 {
  vector[j].push_back(blocks[i]);
 flag = true;
 }
 else
  if(flag)
  {
   j++;
   flag = flase;
  }
}
```

Comment: in your code do
vector<vector<double> > clusters(blocks.size());

Comment: its throwing error because you are accessing elements of empty array i.e cluster is empty and you are trying to access it using operator[]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, I'd do something simple like:

```
bool wasNeg = true;
for(blocks) {
    if(isNegative()) {
      wasNeg = true;
    } else {
        if(wasNeg) {
            outVec.push_back(vector());
        }
        outVec.back().push_back(value);
        wasNeg = false;
    }
 }
```

This always inserts in the latest vector in your output vector. Blocks are separated by pushing a new vector only if there were negative values in between.

Comment: Hey, but no.. if I have the following `new_vals.back().push_back(blocks[i]);` I just get an error: ` no matching function for call to 'std::vector<double>::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<double> > >::value_type&)'
`

Comment: Is you new_vals a `vector<vector<double>>` ?